# Convert java Optional to Kotlin Arrow Option

Tags: kotlin, arrow-kt

What would be the best way to convert Java `Optional` to Arrows `Option`? I was expected to have something out-of-box, but it's not there. Something like:

```
fun <T> Optional<T>.toOption(): Option<T> = if (this.isPresent) Some(this.get()) else none()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such function at the moment, but such a contribution would be welcomed!

Arrow however does not recommend using `Option` unless absolutely necessary. The only use-case being *nested nulls*, which is the limitation for ReactiveX implementation of RxJava & Project Reactor. Both libraries don't allow `null` being used for their generic value `A` in `Flowable`, `Flux`, `Mono`, etc.

Analogue, you cannot use `null` as an *empty signal* for generic code in Kotlin. Unless `A` is constraint to be non-null by using `A : Any`.

Only in both cases should you use Arrow's Option, otherwise using Kotlin's nullable type is recommended by the Arrow maintainers.

Comment: Interesting, I was actually under the impression that we should use `Option` instead of nullable type; hum; do you maybe have a link to the statement?

Comment: Sadly, this is currently not very explicit in the documentation but there has been many discussions within the group of maintainers, and users.

The Arrow team is currently actively working on improving the documentation to include such statements to make this more explicit but I cannot currently link a statement in the documentation.

Comment: No worries, glad that you let me know. Tbh, I was expecting Option to be commonly used, similar to in scala, for example